# Casting a neighboor memory of a defined (known) one

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Let this matrix to be considered as a memory.

```
                                        p00 p01 p02 p03 p04 p05 p06.... p0n
                                        p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 p15    .... p1n
                                        .   .   P22 .   .   .      .... p2n
 Abstraction of the memory              .   .   .   .   .   .      .... .
                                        .   .   .   .   .   .      .... .
                                        .   .   .   .   .   .      .... .
                                        .   .   .   .   .   .      .... pnn
```

And `p01` is a known case which stores an `int`.

For example :

```
int *int_ptr;
int var{42};

int_ptr = &var;

/*Working*/
```

Now, i want to store at `p02` (near `p01`) a `char`, so it's reachable to find a logic, and we can deduce the next starting adress (`&var + sizeof(decltype(var))`)

So, how can we reserve the next case for a different type (different size), using the pointer (or reference), and casting it ?

```
int *int_ptr;
int  i_value{42};
char c_value{'c'};

int_ptr = &var;

/*How can we store the char data juste near the int one*/
```

EDIT : removed unused dynamic memory allocation (leaked) `int *int ptr = new int` corrected by @Eljay

Comment: `delete int_ptr;` is undefined behavior, because of `int_ptr = &var;`, and the previous `int *int_ptr = new int;` is leaked.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't, and you don't want to.**

1. You don't decide where objects go; the runtime does (and, indirectly, the operating system). It's much better at efficiently arranging things than you are.
2. Using pointer arithmetic to "reach" another object in that way has undefined behaviour. You can't navigate the memory space like that.

   It's tempting to think of everything as "just bytes", but that's not really true (C++ is an *abstraction*), and you must stick to the rules unless you want to come a-cropper of various optimisations responsible for producing a program that runs in a decent amount of time.

   You may only use pointer arithmetic to navigate within an array of objects (which can include an implicit array of `char` that make up a single object, if you're aliasing for some reason).

If you're desperate for memory locality (because you've determined, by measurement, that you really need it) then put your objects in a class so that they'll be roughly next to each other in memory.

Also, your example is broken; you allocated an `int`, then chucked away your pointer to it, set the pointer to the address of a local variable, then tried to `delete` the local variable. There is no value (or meaning) in this.

Comment: While any reasonable implementation results in function local objects having high locality (because they always implement them using a stack) I wonder whether or not this is required by the standard.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no it's not required, and no they are not always implemented using a stack. Sometimes they are stored in registers, sometimes they are optimized and not stored at all, and theoretically they can even be stored in memory. The standard just mandates what their lifetime, scope and visibility is.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the edit, but those paragraphs are part of point #2